# Type The nested type CubeRanks cannot hide an enclosing type

Tags: java, plugins

I have a problem with my java plugin.
This is never i had before. Normal it went all good.

Here is the code:

```
package me.brian.CubeRanks;

import me.brian.CubeRanks.CubeRanks;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;


public class CubeRanks {

    public class CubeRanks extends JavaPlugin {

        public static CubeRanks plugin;
        public final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
        public boolean enabled = false;
        public final PlayerListener pl = new PlayerListener(this);
        public final ArrayList<Player> OreHunterUsers = new ArrayList<Player>();
        public String cr = "[CubeRanks] ";


        @Override
        public void onEnable() {
            log.info(cr + "is now enabled.");   
            PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
            pm.registerEvents(pl, this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDisable() {
            log.info(cr + "is now disabled.");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
            if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("CubeRanks")) {
                if(args.length==0) {
                    if(!enabled) {
                        enabled = true;
                        ((Player) sender).sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + cr + "is now enabled");
                    }
                    else {
                        enabled = false;
                        ((Player) sender).sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + cr + "is now disbaled");
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone see whats wrong?

Whole Error Code:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The nested type CubeRanks cannot hide an enclosing type CubeRanks.java  /CubeRanks/src/me/brian/CubeRanks   line 16 Java Problem

Photo of the error: [This is the error](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Y7n8p8zVgFM/UgVEpppdVuI/AAAAAAAAAIw/Gnt2s-B960E/w1553-h812-no/Error.PNG)

Comment: You can't have inner class name same as enclosing class.

Comment: It can't. Check it again. There must be something you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a class enclosing a class of the same name. I'm not sure why you have that outer `CubeRanks` class, but either get rid of the outer one, or rename one of them.

```
public class CubeRanks { // remove or rename

    public class CubeRanks extends JavaPlugin { // or rename this
        ...
    }

}
```

Syntactically, the reason why you can't have an inner class that is the same name as its outer class is to remove the following ambiguity:

```
public class Ambiguous {
    public class Ambiguous {
        Ambiguous a; // <-- which type is Ambiguous referring to here?
    } 
}
```

You could argue that the most recent enclosing type name could take precedence, but then how would you refer to the outer type? While there are theoretically ways to design a language around all of that, it's easier to just disallow it.